# Error in running webDrive for selenium Python Binding

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have followed all the steps mention in [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html#selenium-remote-webdriver)
to install and  run selelnium python binding and  finally after running selenium I got the message 
INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub as mentioned in the doc 
but when I go to the python console and type

`>>> from selenium import webdrive`

I get the error :

`Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
ImportError: cannot import name webdrive`

Comment: >>> from selenium import webdriver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name webdriver

Comment: So you import `webdriver` or `webdrive`? Please update question with actual one

Comment: I tried with both "webdrive" and  "webdriver"

Comment: have you checked the `webdriver` folder in your `C:\PythonXX\Lib\site-packages\selenium` ?

Comment: It is there in the path

Comment: Just now I read somewhere that we need to delete selenium.pyc file if its there in the same folder. I tried that also but it didnt work :(